# NativeScript Sidekick doesn't start

Tags: nativescript

When trying to start Sidekick, the loading window appears and then I get notifications about errors. The errors get cut off due to the small size of the notification area. I'm using MacOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Sidekick logs for information what is going on. They are located at `~/Library/Application Support/NativeScriptSidekick/Logs/`. I recommend you to clean the content of the dir and start Sidekick after that. This will produce several files in which you should find the exact error that prevents Sidekick from starting.